# Google Map Javascript Api v3 places autocomplete Not Showing Proper Results In iPhone App

Tags: javascript, iphone, google-maps-api-3, mapkit

I am making one Map Kit app in iPhone and used "Google Map Javascript Api v3 places autocomplete". I followed the document given by Google http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/autocomplete.html and created API key also as instructions by Google.

But the problem is that when i got the results then every time it returned "Request Denied" and shows no values to me.

Answer (score 1):

Just check whether u are using v=3.exp in the URL. I figured it out after several attempts:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=

Hope this helps.